# Sending a file directly to database

Tags: java, database, outputstream

I wish, in this portion of code, instead of saving the file to my computer and then opening again, to read it, and send to the database directly. I appreciate the help!

```
            inputstr_id = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            String id_moradia = inputstr_id.readUTF();

            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("filename.bmp");

            final byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
            int read = -1;
            while ((read = inputstr_id.read(buffer)) != -1)
                out.write(buffer, 0, read);

            out.close();

            try {
                File imgfile = new File("filename.bmp");

                  FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(imgfile);

                  PreparedStatement pre = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE moradia SET image = ? where id_moradia = ?");
                  pre.setBinaryStream(1,(InputStream)fin,(int)imgfile.length());
                  pre.setString(2,id_moradia);
                  pre.executeUpdate();

            }
            catch (SQLException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();}
            System.out.println("A moradia ID: "+ id_moradia + " fez o upload de uma foto com sucesso");
```

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Comment: This code works. Though I want to not have to save the file to my computer. I think when a lot of users uses my program, it will overload my server!

Comment: Can't you just delete everything before the try block and replace `FileInputstream(imgfile)` with `DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream())`?